# How to access layouts of a sub-module from another sub-module?

Tags: android

I have two modules in my android project. And I want both of these modules to access the layout files of other module and perform operations like Intent().

But, Using `compile project (':x ')` is not working for this.

Edit:
Both the modules are successfully added into the project and gradle was synced properly and manifests are merged. I want to how to access res/layout files of one module from another module's java file.For context, I have activityA.xml in module 1 which I need in module two so that when a button is clicked in module 2, it transits to ActivityA.xml with intent.

Comment: Be more specific and I will be happy to help. Are you having problems including additional modules into your project? Are they included but you can't compile them individually? what exactly is your issue.

Comment: @Sam updated. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok so to use resources from another module you must do a few things.

Determine how you will package and use your module. Is the module "just" for this app or is it used in others.

If it is used by more than one project then I recommend packaging it as an AAR and hosting in a Maven Repo of your own and pulling via Gradle to avoid project dependencies on the code base itself.

If it is only used by this project then you must do a couple things as well.

1) Ensure that the settings.gradle has the module included. You can do this with simple :moduleName if it is local to the project directory. Otherwise you can do it with

```
include 'myLib'
project(':myLib').projectDir = new File('../../../workspace/libs/myLib')
```

Once you have done this confirm Gradle Sync pulls the module into the project. And not just an empty folder with an IML. If it is an empty folder confirm your path and try again.

Step 2) So you successfully imported your module and you can see it in your directory. However, you can't have a module depend on the app and the app depend on the module. It is called circular dependency, so you must only have the app depend on the module. Go to your app's module the one where it has

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

and go to the dependency section and include

```
    compile ':myLib'
```

Now you need to confirm your compile myLib is working (myLib is the name of your lib). To confirm you can do an assembleRelease from the terminal and see if it has any issue or you can do a Gradlesync as well.

If it worked you can now import resources or files into any Activity of the parent app module by simply including the import statement at the top.

Now you can do things like HelperClass.doSomething (where helperClass lives in myLibs).

So let's take it one step further. Maybe you need HelperClass to be able to respond to the app module. Then you must supply an interface inside the myLib of IMyCallBack with whatever methods you would call out to and have the parent module calling activity implement the interface for calling back.

Does this answer your question or are you having another issue. A there should be no issue accessing the content of your child module if your dependency is setup correctly.

Comment: Modules were successfully added and synced. I'm able to use them in the parent app. But, I want the files of submodules to be accessible to other submodules in the app. Like, all the files of module A should be accessible by module B and vice versa. Is it possible?

Comment: No that is called circular dependency. You may have module A depend on Module B "OR" you may have Module B depend on Module A. You may NOT do both. If you have code that is needed by both Module A and Module B, then I would suggest moving it to Module C and having Module A and B both depend on Module C. Does that make sense.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to import module A into module B with the import statement? Both the modules are already part of the main project.

Comment: The module include is part of the settings.gradle. The module dependency is setup through the individual build.gradle files. Module B has a build.gralde file. Add :moduleA to the compile dependency section of Module B and you are done

Comment: i am refactoring my project MVP pattern to MVVM pattern and i create a new java module for this.i have views like SplashActivity, LoginActivity and MainActivity.I changed LoginActivity and presenter class to new LoginActivity and viewmodel class and keep in new module. In the existing flow Splash -> Login-> Main but Login class is new class with viewmodel in new module. So i need to implament both side dependency. So When i add implementation module1 in module2 and module2 in module1, i am getting  "Circular dependency between the following tasks" error.

Comment: You can't have one project reference a second project and then the second project reference the first, it is recursion in the build process. Your modules should be singular focused on what they do and not need to rely on another one of your custom libraries. For example if you make a logging library don't include that in your bluetooth library or other libraries, just use standard logging in modules. So you have to architect things in a way to avoid circular dependencies. Otherwise, you have to get creative in changing package names and creating aars of each to include with each other. messy.